# Guice injector.getInstance() - good practice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Let's say I have two applications sharing the same library. This library contains common classes like DAOs, Utils, etc. Everything in the shared library is wired with Guice. My two apps depend on this library but do not have a direct dependency on Guice.

```
 ______    ______    ______
|      |  |      |  |      |
| APP1 |->| LIB  |<-| APP2 |
'------'  '------'  '------'
```

I currently use something like this:

```
static <T> Utils.getInstanceOf (Class<T> type);
```

which is simply a wrapper for:

```
injector.getInstance (Class<T> type);
```

But the guice docs say:

> When feasible, avoid using this method, in favor of having Guice
>   inject your dependencies ahead of time.

So what's the best way to provide dependency injection for the two apps without having to manually bind them in a Guice module?

Comment: Does your design rule out the use of `@Inject`?

Comment: Not at all. I use it all over the shared lib. Forgot to mention that client apps have servlets and Jersey REST classes in them - i.e webapps running in a servlet container (non-JavaEE).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> So what's the best way to provide dependency injection for the two
>   apps without having to manually bind them in a Guice module?

There is no such way. You either embrace Guice totally or do not use it and pass your dependencies explicitly. Well, structuring your code in such way so you never directly create class dependencies, passing them instead through a constructor, also may be called 'dependency injection', but I'm sure this is not what you meant. If you do not want to use Guice in your apps, you won't be able to get anything better than `getInstance()`, which is ugly, especially because you're using *static* wrapper.

Ideally your library should provide a module which you can install via `Guice.createInjector()` in your applications, or, in the other way around, the library should provide an `Injector` instance which you can use in your applications by using `createChildInjector()` and providing application-specific modules. Slight modification of this approach is passing application-specific modules to the library so they will be used to create `Injector`. I have recently written Guice-based API over custom servlet-like interface which didn't support any kind of DI at all using the last approach, and it is working perfectly.

It is not at all hard to use Guice in servlet or Jersey environment. The latter, for example, has out-of-the-box integration with Guice (at least, in 1.x versions). Guice [servlet extension](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets) is also very good and convenient. Just try it and see for yourself.

Comment: So it's OK to pass an `Injector` instance around? I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: @AlexB No-no-no. I didn't mean that. I guess I didn't make myself clear and probably made a mistake. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

> `static <T> Utils.getInstanceOf (Class<T> type);`

What you have ended up with is a [Service Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern).

While in a few small cases this it is acceptable for the `injector` to escape into other creational objects, I don't think this one of them. You have ended up with all the disadvantages of a Service Locator and all the advantages can be had by using the tool you are already using.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a method that needs to create a new instance of class C at runtime, bind a Provider to your class. C would be bound in the usual way, e.g.

```
public CModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Overide
    public void configure() {
        bind(C.class).to(CImpl.class);
    }
}
```

The class that creates C instances would look like this:

```
class UserOfC {
    private Provider<C> cProvider;
    ...

    @Inject
    UserOfC(Provider<C> cProvider, ...) {
        this.cProvider = cProvider;
        ...
    }

    public void doSomethingWithAC (...) {
        C myC = cProvider.get();  // not a singleton; new instance created!
        ...
    }
}
```

Guice supportes Provider injection free for nothing. If C is bound, you can inject a Provider as easily as you can inject an instance of C.

***Additional Suggestions:***

I strongly recommend that you inject all dependencies at construction, if at all possible, even if it requires writing a few more lines of code. I've used Guice for years, and have yet to need partial construction or any other advanced feature.

When I am faced with the need for partial injection, I generally write my own factory. I find it much easier to understand and debug when I write the code.

Answer (score 2):

The "usual" pattern of using an injector is to set it up in some top-level entry point of you project (in a servlet scenario, using Guice-Servlet, this would be the GuiceServletContextListener). You may want to configure an individual injector at an entry point to some dependency and make it responsible for wiring that dependency, for the sake of modularization. If you want both, individual bindings and the bindings from the parent project, in your dependencies, than you can create a child injector that delegates to its parent if no binding is found. Guice supports this.

However, it seem strange to me that you want to set up an injector inside a dependency and use it in your main app(s). This would mean that the dependency knows about all bindings required by the main app(s). I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve with this approach. Is it that your two apps have the same/a very similar binding setup and you don't want to repeat it? In this case you should define a module with all that bindings configurations once (maybe in a dependency) and use it when setting up the injector at the entry points of each of your apps. That much in regard to your scenario.

To your question in general. I think its good practice to avoid explicitly passing the injector. Whenever you do this, you work against the idea of dependency injection as being a transparent project and you tie yourself to a concrete injection framework. In most cases you can avoid explicit references to the injector by using [Providers](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provider.html) and [Factories](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject#AssistedInject).

Comment: Thanks! I mainly try to not repeat code and also have a default module  in the shared lib, containing the bindings for the default interface implementations. The main apps don't provide their own modules and bindings yet. So in a way the shared lib knows about all the default bindings used in other apps.

Comment: You yourself saying "yet" implies that there may be individual bindings in the future. Which is perfectly fine and can easily be achieved, given that your apps create their own injector, using the common module. I see injector-configuration code like a configuration file: It's perfectly okay to change it, it should be located in the app that it configures -- because that's where I would search for it --, and it should be in a class that does nothing else than configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it ok to pass injector this way.

Even we have done something similar with our wicket application, so for non non-wicket pages we have simply used `injector.get.inject(this)` and passed in the constructor.

and it works perfect.

Hope this helps.